# Run SSIS only when complete file is present in the folder

Tags: file, ssis, etl

I have developed a ETL which is consuming flat files. The size of flat files varies from 250 MB - 300 MB.
It is working absoultely fine when file present in the folder. But it fails when the file is in generation mode.

Ex: This ETL package runs from 8 AM to 10 AM to check whether the file is present in the folder or not. Now, at any instance(let say 9 AM) if the file is starting generated and till now it is 10 MB. ETL start processing the file and just hang  and fail after 4-5 min ( hang at script task which is reading that the file is present in the folder or not).

What is the best way to trigger SSIS package  only when the file generation is completely done?

Note: I have no control over the file generation.

Comment: You can use the 3rd party [File Properties Task](http://filepropertiestask.codeplex.com/) and test for `FileIsReadable `

Comment: @OcasoProtal Thanks for the link but my client will not allow us to use any third party tool. Because they have other projects/jobs also running on prod and that will be a huge terror for them. We already tried to suggest him other third party tool but he just want us to develop the same functionality. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `For Loop Container` with a Boolean variable `bFileAccessible`:

- The Init expression is `@bFileAccessible=False`
- The Eval expression is `@bFileAccessible==False`

Inside the `For Loop Container` add a `Script Task` with a ReadWriteVariable `User::bFileAccessible` and the following C# script (showing only the `Main()` method):

```
    public void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            using (Stream stream = new FileStream("Path\to\your\file", FileMode.Open))
            {
                Dts.Variables["bFileAccessible"].Value = true;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Dts.Variables["bFileAccessible"].Value = false;
        }

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

You should also use a variable for the filename and maybe a little wait interval. For more information about the script see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876473/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-file-is-in-use).

Answer (score 1):

Check the FIle modified time everytime and comapre the same with previous one.... 
it's not good logic but a good idea if no perfect alternative

Comment: This will not work when the generation process is stalled for some time.